# Displaying whole image by clicking on a subplot

Tags: matlab, events, image-processing

I croped some parts of images and displayed them in one figure with subplots. Number of subplots are not certain. I read images from a file then crop them. My aim is that when I click or double click on an subplot, I want to see whole image in new figure.

I want to give an example just to make clear my question. if I click on first subplot, I want to see whole cameraman image in new figure.

[image]

Is it possible? If it is possible, What is the way?

Comment: Create a GUI and put 4 axes for the 4 subplots and then put pushbuttons on top of the axes or use mouse callback functions?

Comment: @Divakar I know this method but my question is not only for 4 image. I edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example uses the ButtonDownFcn that can be added to most matlab plot commands.
Just copy both functions into one file and run the "interactivePlot" function.

The list_of_images contains all matrices that shall be plotted.
The number of matrices is flexible. However, you have to adjust the subplot command...

```
function interactivePlot
    list_of_images = {rand(5), rand(10), rand(50), rand(100)}

    for ii = 1:length(list_of_images)
        subplot(2,2,ii)
        imagesc(list_of_images{ii}, 'ButtonDownFcn', @newFigure1)
    end
end

function newFigure1(h1, h2)
    figure()
    data = get(h1, 'CData');
    imagesc(data)
end
```

Comment: It works. However, my images are not displayed with their original colours. They are gray images but looking colorful. I don't under stand the reason

Comment: @sigara I guess you can use colormap('gray') to get them in grayscal

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, change your function like below then it will be solved:

```
function newFigure1(h1, h2)
    figure()
    data = get(h1, 'CData');
    colormap(gray);
    imagesc(data)
end
```