# Removing a subplot in a figure by clicking on it. Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, events, matlab-figure, subplot

[image]

I have this figure. When a user click on an subplot the image will be displayed in different figure. I want that when user make right click on a subplot the image in this subpolt will be removed.

Is it possible? If yes, what is the way?

P.S: Here my previus question about click and display image in different figure

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160853/displaying-whole-image-by-clicking-on-a-subplot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily done by some small changes in the solution from the question you refer to.

The following code lets you left click an image to get it in a new figure window and right click an image to remove it from the subplot:

```
function interactivePlot
    list_of_images = {rand(5), rand(10), rand(50), rand(100)};

    for ii = 1:length(list_of_images)
        subplot(2,2,ii);
        a = imagesc(list_of_images{ii}, 'ButtonDownFcn', @newFigure1);
        set(a,'UserData',ii);
    end
end


function newFigure1(h1,~)
    switch get(gcf,'SelectionType')
        case 'normal'
            figure();
            data = get(h1, 'CData');
            imagesc(data);
        case 'alt'
            delete(get(h1,'Parent'));
    end
end
```